# Adding a transition effect in EventDrops D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, event-drops

I am using [EventDrops](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops) for displaying an event series. 
I am new to D3 and I am having tough time understanding the code. 
Using Eventdrops we can zoom in and out in the time series. 
Now I want to add a transition that on load the events should be fully zoomed in and then slowly zoom out.

How can I do that? 
I am not able to trigger the zoom effect on the SVG element.